# Requirejs, jshint and naming conventions

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bower, jshint

Can you using dots and hyphens in the naming conventions of the paths of requirejs?

```
  paths: {
    chosen: '../../bower_components/chosen/chosen.jquery',
    dateBuilderPlugin: 'vendor/dateBuilder-plugin',
    jquery: '../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
    jquery.ui.widget: '../../bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget',
    jquery.iframe-transport: '../../bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport',
    jqueryFileupload: '../../bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload',
    jqueryFileuploadProcess: '../../bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process',
    jqueryFileuploadImage: '../../bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-image',
    jqueryFileuploadValidate: '../../bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate',

},
```

When I use this naming convention (`jquery.iframe-transport`) I get a duplicate key error in jshint. It says jquery is already defined, as its ignoring the name after the `-` or `.`.

I am using RequireJS and jshint and bower. The naming conventions are set in a plugin I am uisng unless I save the files and reference them manually, which defeats the object of using bower etc.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are asking whether the *keys* in your `paths` object can have dashes and periods in them. Yes, they can. However, you must use quotes. So `"jquery.ui.widget": ...` with quotes, not `jquery.ui.widget: ...` without quotes. Same thing for `jquery.iframe-transport`: you must use quotes. So `"jquery.iframe-transport": ...`.

This is a JavaScript syntax constraint, not a constraint imposed by RequireJS.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I meant, thank you very much. Thats working now :-)